# Theorem about non extendable solution of an ODE Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, cauchy-problem

I' ve found in a book without a proof  the following theorem:
Let $A=I\times \mathbb{R}$, where  I=]a,b[ is an interval with   $-\infty\leq a<b\leq +\infty$, be a set in which  the  function f(x,y): $(x,y) \subset A  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is defined, continous and locally
lipschitzian in y uniformly in x . Let
\begin{cases}
 y'(x)=f(x,y)  \\ y(x_0)=y_0      
\end{cases}
be a Cauchy problem with $x_0\in I$.
If $\tilde{y}$  is a not exctendable unique solution of the problem defined in a maximal interval $]a_{m},b_m[$ then we have that:
(i)$b=b_m$ or $b_m<b $   and  $ \lim_{x \to b_m^{-}} |\tilde{y}(x)| = +\infty$ 
(ii)$a=a_m$ or $a_m>a $   and  $ \lim_{x \to a_m^{+}} |\tilde{y}(x)| = +\infty$ 
Now I ask where can I find the proof of this theorem and the possible usability in finding the maximal interval of existency of the solution of a Cauchy problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general statement is that for any ODE IVP
$$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)),~~y(x_0)=y_0$$
where $f$ has an open domain
$$D\subset \Bbb R\times \Bbb R^n,~~ (x_0,y_0)\in D,$$
and $f$ is continuous and locally Lipschitz in $y$ on $D$, ... , then the (unique) maximal solution leaves any compact set inside of $D$.

The proof is essentially that any solution that ends in a compact set has a limit point, and can thus be continued by the local solution of the IVP starting at the limit point.

In your situation, take the compact sets $[a+\delta,b-\delta]\times[-N,N]\subset D$.